# Convert ListView to ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listadapter, expandablelistadapter

I've got an `Activity` with a `ListView`, filled with the help of an `Adapter`, that extends a parameterized `ArrayAdapter<A>`. Class `A`, that parameterizes this `Adapter` encapsulates a `List` of objects of class `B`. I want my `ExpandableListView` to contain objects of class `A` as groups and objects of class B to be their children. Is there a simple way to perform this conversion? I was not able to find any classes, implementing `ExpandableListAdapter`, that can be parameterized.